# Getting the word the appeears after a specific word in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this string.

String message = 'QG935XSVSD Confirmed. Your account balance was: M-PESA Account : Ksh0.00 on 9/7/22 at 12:33 PM. Transaction cost, Ksh0.00. Dial *334# now to get your stamped M-Pesa Statement.'

I want to get the word that appears right after cost, in this case Ksh0.00 . I would try and pick the word by its position but the message might get additional words affecting its length.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the string structure, simplest solution would probably  be `.split()` method.

```dart
final cost = message.split('cost, ')[1].split(' ')[0];
```